# codeigniter 4 Call to a member function getResult() on bool error on live server but not on local host

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

After working on a project on my local host, the the system works perfectly but after hosting on a live server, i noticed most of my function are giving the "Call to a member function getResult() on bool" error.

```
    $data['user_payouts']  = $payoutModel->where('p_uid', $logged_user_Id)->join('invest', 'invest.i_id = payout.p_invest_id', 'left')->paginate(10);
    $data['pager']         = $payoutModel->pager;
    $data['perPage']       = 10;
    $data['total']         = $payoutModel->countAll();
    $data['page']          = isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

Comment: question in unclear and need  more debug information ( Like what line in what file is throwing the exception or the code snippet for that )

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. Can you provide more debug information? Like what line in what file is throwing the exception? And the code snippet for that?

From the error message it sound like the result of a PHP expression is calculated as a bool (true or false) and thus nothing else (*getResult()*) can be called on a bool.